# Is this a UITableView? How does this work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

[image]

Click the header section(or whatever it calls) will unfold the relative subcells,and the left triangle get rotated.

I have no idea how to code this.Is there anyone help me? Any code snippets would be great help.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can now see how to properly do it in an 
[example by apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 3):

That is a UITableView. You will need to add transparent buttons or a similar UIControl to the section headers to trap the tap events and then load the cells underneath

Comment: The section headers' positions are not fixed,that way you said would require to recaculate the position everytime you tap the header section.It is too complicated,is there other elegant way?Thanks though.

Comment: UIKit should take care of the positioning automatically as long as you add the controls as subviews inside the section headers.